# Visual Studio extension: Change the hint path of an assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension and I would like to change the hint path of an assembly reference of a C#-project without to trigger the "File Modification Detected"-dialog.

```
<Reference Include="SomeAssembly">
  <HintPath>C:\ChangeMe\SomeAssembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But in the VSLangProj110.Reference5-interface I can't find any property that I can use. (Accessed through VSLangProj140.VSProject3.References)

Comment: Why? Standard assemblies are under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\..." and managed by Visual Studio, your own source should be linked via project reference, and other binaries should ideally be imported as a Nuget package.

Comment: We place all internal libraries in a specific directory. But when I add an assembly to a project they are added with an absolute path. I want to replace this path with a path that uses an environment variable. So you dont have to change anything when you are using the project on a other maschine.

Comment: "ideally be imported as a Nuget package" not every dev team has a nuget server setup.  There's plenty of reasons to include either in-house libraries or third party packages that are not nuget packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project is outdated. Here is an updated working solution.

```
foreach (var dteProject in dte.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>())
{
    // You can edit the project through an object of Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project 
    var buildProject = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects(dteProject.FullName).First();
    foreach (var item in buildProject.Items.Where(obj => obj.ItemType == "Reference"))
    {
        var newPath = SomeMethod(item.GetMetadata("HintPath"));

        item.SetMetadataValue("HintPath", newPath);
    }

    // But you have to save through an object of EnvDTE.Project
    dteProject.Save();
}
```

Comment: Did you publish this extension by any chance ?

Comment: I published the source code on github (https://github.com/thoenissen/luma), but the extension is in an early state.

Answer (score 0):

I create a demo and reproduce your issue on my side. I think it is a by design issue, if you modify the project outside the environment, it will popup the "File Modification Detected" dialog, we need to change it by manually.

you could post a feedback on the following link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Update:

```
DTE2 dte = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
            EnvDTE.Project currentProject = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1);

            // Create a new Project object.
            Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project project = new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project();

            project.Load(currentProject.FullName);

            foreach (BuildItemGroup ig in project.ItemGroups)
            {
                //var items = ig.ToArray();

                foreach (BuildItem item in ig.ToArray())
                {
                    if (item.Include == "ClassLibrary1")
                    {
                        item.Include = "Utils";
                        item.SetMetadata("HintPath", @"C:\relativePath\Utils.dll");
                    }
                }
            }
            project.Save(currentProject.FullName);
```

Comment: How do you change the hint path in your Demo? I cant find a way to change it through EnvDTE/VSLangProj.

Comment: I create a demo via Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project, it popup the window after save the project.